# callback is added in JSON request of jQuery

Tags: jquery, json, callback, jquery-1.5

I have these javascript codes in a page:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(function() { 
   $.getJSON("http://example.com/index.php/grid/fetch-grid", function(jsonData) {
    if (jsonData.status === true) {
        $("#parserFilterGridContainer").html(jsonData.content);
    } else {
        // Alert that loading failed
        alert(jsonData.content);
    }
    });
});
</script>
```

when I check it in firebug the url requested from the server is

```
"http://example.com/index.php/grid/fetch-grid?callback=.... (some numbers)"
```

instead of 
   "http://example.com/index.php/$$$call$$$/grid/fetch-grid"

My jQuery version is v1.5.1.
Is it because of my jQuery version?
How can I resolve it ?

Comment: jQuery 1.5.2 doesn't exhibit this behaviour with the exact code above. http://jsfiddle.net/LRsRy/ Could you maybe have some global Ajax settings elsewhere in the code? See http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajaxSetup/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok,It is solved now. I upgrade my jquery from 1.5.1 to 1.7 and the problem is solved.It seems v1.5.1 treats with getJSON as JSONP instead of JSON.